# CodeIgniter baseurl not working on localhost

Tags: php, configuration, localhost, base-url

I am trying to use `baseurl()` in my application, but it's not working. I've attached two photos, [image: here] and [image: here]. Can anybody help me solve this?

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/class-19/';
```

Comment: sorry, please say me again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hiii...Please replace  baseurl() to ***base_url().***

Comment: please change autoload.php :- $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `base_url()`, you must first have the `URL Helper` loaded. This can be done either in `application/config/autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or, manually:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Once it's loaded, be sure to keep in mind that base_url() doesn't implicitly print or echo out anything, rather it returns the value to be printed:

```
echo base_url();
```

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'pdt');